# Drupal panel pages

Tags: drupal, drupal7

Tengo un problema con drupal, en concreto con la creación de alías para páginas creadas mediante page manager con panels.

Necesito añadir un url alias diferente por cada idioma, en la creación de página me deja añadir el path pero no me deja añadir varios (uno por idioma), a la hora de intentar añadirlo en patterns no me da la opción de panel pages, y en url aliases tampoco puedo debido a que tiene una variable y no puedo usar variables.

He probado también translation sets pero no puedo usar ninguna variable (En este caso necesito el hellotext).

La página que quiero añadirle los url alias tiene el siguiente path:

```
lalala/lalala/%hellotext/lalala (Siendo hellotext un argumento en panel).
```

Necesitaría que el alias fuera en castellano así y en inglés cambiar el lalala por lololo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes instalar el modulo [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) este modulo te permite crear urls para diferentes idiomas, para usarlo vas a configuracion y luego buscas alias de url y asi podras cambiar los patrones por cada nodo